# How can I display all numbers in range 0-N that are "super numbers"

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. The program asks the user for a number *N*.
2. The program is supposed to displays all numbers in range 0-*N* that are "super numbers".

   > Super number: is a number such that the sum of the factorials of its
   >   digits equals the number.

   #### Examples:

   - 12  != 1! + 2! = 1 + 2 = 3 (it's not super)
   - 145 = 1! + 4! + 5! = 1 + 24 + 120 (is super)
3. The part I seem to be stuck at is when the program displays all numbers in range 0-*N* that are "super numbers". I have concluded I need a loop in order to solve this, but I do not know how to go about it. So, for example, the program is supposed to read all the numbers from 0-50 and whenever the number is super it displays it. So it only displays 1 and 2 since they are considered super

   ```
   enter integer: 50
   2 is super
   1 is super
   ```
4. I have written two functions; the first is a regular factorial program, and the second is a program that sums the factorials of the digits:

   ```
   number = int(input ("enter integer: "))

   def factorial (n):
       result = 1 
       i = n * (n-1)
       while n >= 1:
           result = result * n
           n = n-1
       return result

   #print(factorial(number))

   def breakdown (n):
       breakdown_num = 0
       remainder = 0

       if n < 10:
           breakdown_num += factorial(n)
           return breakdown_num
       else:
           while n > 10:
               digit = n % 10
               remainder = n // 10 
               breakdown_num += factorial(digit) 
               #print (str(digit))
               #print(str(breakdown_num))
               n = remainder

           if n < 10 :
               #print (str(remainder))
               breakdown_num += factorial(remainder)
               #print (str(breakdown_num))

           return breakdown_num

   #print(breakdown(number))
   if (breakdown(number)) == number:
       print(str(number)+ " is super")
   ```

Comment: Make a function that takes a single number and returns whether it is 'super' or not. You will find that function useful.

Comment: That's a lot of text for the question "How do I iterate over a bunch of numbers"... Or did I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: @Aran-Fey just wanted to provide context for the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I would slightly change how main code is executed, by moving main parts to `if __name__ == '__main__'`, which will execute after running this `.py` as main file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = int(input ("enter integer: "))
    if (breakdown(number)) == number:
        print(str(number)+ " is super")
```

After that it seems much clearer what you should do to loop over numbers, so instead of above it would be:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = int(input ("enter integer: "))
    for i in range(number+1):
        if (breakdown(i)) == i:
            print(str(i)+ " is super")
```

Example input and output:

```
enter integer: 500
1 is super
2 is super
145 is super
```

Small advice - you don't need to call `str()` in `print()` - `int` will be shown the same way anyway.

Comment: your response is very helpful could you explain what you mean by moving main parts to if __name__ == '__main__'

Comment: By "main parts" I mean "core" part of your code - those functions/statements that you want to run after running, so in your case everything thats not inside any methods - so those lines I put in `if __name__ == '__main__':`. 

That way it's much easier to see what will happen when you run the code - everything inside this `if` will be executed.

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':` by itself is statement that will be used when you run script by itself - it won't be used if the module is imported or used in any other way, its good practice to get used to it. After getting some grasp of the language itself, check https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Yes, it's good to know about `if __name__ == '__main__':`. But it's even better if you can put the main code into a `main` function, and just have a `main()` call inside the `if __name__ == '__main__` block, rather than just dumping the code into the global context. Of course for small scripts & example code there's nothing wrong with putting code into the global space, but it's certainly neater (and often more efficient) if you wrap the code in functions & minimize the amount of live code in the global space, which should be mostly inhabited by class & function definitions.

Answer (score 8):

Existing answers already show how to do the final loop to tie your functions together. Alternatively, you can also make use of more builtin functions and libraries, like `sum`, or `math.factorial`, and for getting the digits, you can just iterate the characters in the number's string representation.

This way, the problem can be solved in a single line of code (though it might be better to move the is-super check to a separate function).

```
def issuper(n):
    return sum(math.factorial(int(d)) for d in str(n)) == n

N = 1000
res = [n for n in range(1, N+1) if issuper(n)]
# [1, 2, 145]
```

Answer (score 4):

I haven't done much Python in a long time but I tried my own attempt at solving this problem which I think is more readable. For what it's worth, I'm assuming when you say "displays all numbers in range 0-N" it's an exclusive upper-bound, but it's easy to make it an inclusive upper-bound if I'm wrong.

```
import math


def digits(n):
    return (int(d) for d in str(n))


def is_super(n):
    return sum(math.factorial(d) for d in digits(n)) == n


def supers_in_range(n):
    return (x for x in range(n) if is_super(x))


print(list(supers_in_range(150))) # [1, 2, 145]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create a lookup function that tells you the factorial of a single digit number. Reason being - for `888888` you would recompute the factorial of 8 6 times - looking them up in a dict is much faster.

Add a second function that checks if a number `isSuper()` and then print all that are super:

```
# Lookup table for single digit "strings" as well as digit - no need to use a recursing
# computation for every single digit all the time - just precompute them:
faks = {0:1}
for i in range(10):
    faks.setdefault(i,faks.get(i-1,1)*i) # add the "integer" digit as key
    faks.setdefault(str(i), faks [i])    # add the "string" key as well

def fakN(n):
    """Returns the faktorial of a single digit number"""
    if n in faks:        
        return faks[n]

    raise ValueError("Not a single digit number")

def isSuper(number):
    "Checks if the sum of each digits faktorial is the same as the whole number"
    return sum(fakN(n) for n in str(number)) == number


for k in range(1000):
    if isSuper(k):
        print(k)
```

Output:

```
1
2
145
```

Answer (score 2):

Use range.

```
for i in range(number): # This iterates over [0, N)
    if (breakdown(number)) == number:
        print(str(number)+ " is super")
```

If you want to include number N as well, write as `range(number + 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure about what you are asking for. From the two functions you write, it seems you have solid knowledge about Python programming. But from your question, you don't even know how to write a simple loop.

By only answering your question, what you need in your main function is:

```
for i in range(0,number+1):
    if (breakdown(i)) == i:
        print(str(i)+ " is super")
```

Comment: I did not include my attempt at making a loop because it would make my code a bit more confusing to read but I do struggle with loops and tend to over think them which is why they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
def get(n):
    for i in range(n):
        l1 = list(str(i))
        v = 0
        for j in l1:
                v += math.factorial(int(j))
        if v == i:
                print(i)
```

This will print all the super numbers under `n`.

```
>>> get(400000)
1
2
145
40585
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how efficient the code is but it does produce the desired result :

```
def facto():
  minr=int(input('enter the minimum range  :'))        #asking minimum range
  maxr=int(input('enter the range maximum range :'))   #asking maximum range
  i=minr
  while i <= maxr :
    l2=[]
    k=str(i)
    k=list(k)        #if i=[1,4,5]
    for n in k:      #taking each element
        fact=1
        while int(n) > 0:  #finding factorial of each element
          n=int(n)
          fact=fact*n
          n=n-1

        l2.append(fact) #keeping factorial of each element eg : [1,24,120]
    total=sum(l2)       # taking the sum of l2 list eg 1+24+120 = 145
    if total==i: #checking if sum is equal to the present value of i.145=145
        print(total) # if sum = present value of i than print the number
    i=int(i)
    i=i+1

facto()
```

input : minr =0 , maxr=99999
output : 
1
2
145
40585